# OneDrive configuration and redirect link

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, onedrive-for-business, onedrive

I am new to SharePoint Server.

If I am working with SharePoint Server 2016 on-premises, would I be able to use the OneDrive in the suitenav without Office 365 (even if useres have OneDrive license)?

I have tried following the documentation here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/onedrive-for-business-overview

I cannot activate Recently Shared Items (via PowerShell), and do not know how to configure the link in the SuiteNav on MySites (when you click, it doesn't do anything).

Any advice would help! Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking to set up OneDrive Hybrid where your user's OneDrives are in O365 (i.e. "the cloud") while hooked to SharePoint On-Prem? -- or do you want to use OneDrive completely on-prem?

Comment: @willman I believe the latter - use OneDrive completely on-prem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first setup each of the required pre-requisite services:

- [Managed Metadata Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business#managed-metadata-service)
- ["My" Sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business#my-sites)
- [User Profile Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business#user-profile-service)

The PowerShell commands to activate [Recently Shared Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business#enable-the-recently-shared-items-rsi-cache-to-quickly-populate-the-shared-with-me-view) will **NOT** work until those pre-requisite services are completely configured.  Also note that those commands must be executed **directly on the SharePoint Server**, you must either use Remote Desktop or be physically present at the server to execute those commands, they will not work using a remote PowerShell window on your laptop.  If you have multiple servers in your SharePoint farm, it is recommended that you execute the commands on the machine designated as the "App" server.

Comment: The Managed Metadata, MySites, and User Profile services are all set up. I've tried on both the WFE and App server, but still nothing.